# If $A \to 1$ is an epimorphism in a well-pointed topos, does $A$ have a global element?

Tags: topos-theory, intuitionistic-logic

In a well-pointed topos, it is simple to show that $A$ is an initial object if, and only if, there are no global elements $1 \to A$.

Now suppose that $A \to 1$ is an epimorphism. Then $A$ cannot be an initial object since the map $0 \to 1$ is monic and not an isomorphism, hence cannot be epic (since every monic and epic morphism is an isomorphism in a topos). Then $A$ cannot have no global elements, so by the law of excluded middle, $A$ has a global element.

But now suppose the meta-logic here is intuitionistic. That is, on the metatheoretic level, we do not accept the typical classic axioms like $P \lor \neg P$. Can we still prove that $A$ has a global element whenever $A \to 1$ is epi?

If we cannot prove this, what model can we devise of a metatheory together with a well-pointed topos in which this fact is not true?

Note that this is a special case of a more general classical result I am trying to prove, which follows from the special case. The more general theorem is that in a well-pointed topos, a map $f : A \to B$ is epi iff every global element of $B$ factors through $f$.

The fact that for an epi $f : A \to B$, every global element $g : 1 \to B$ factors through $f$ follows by taking the pullback of $g$ and $f$, noting that the resulting map $h : P \to 1$ must be epi since it's the pullback of an epi, and taking a global element of $P$, which gives rise to a global element of $A$ that $g$ factors through.

Note that generally, when we're dealing with well-pointed toposes in ETCS, we add the external Axiom of Choice which states that every epi splits. This immediately resolves the issue. But I am interested in using well-pointed toposes in intuitionistic meta-logic so that the results can apply to intuitionist set-theory and some varieties of intuitionist type-theory, so I would rather avoid imposing any classical axioms at all on either the meta-logic or the internal logic of the topos except well-pointedness.

Comment: What is a "well-pointed" topos?  I suppose that eliminates counterexamples such as the sheaf on $S^1$ of antiderivatives of the one-form $d\theta$ for which the map to 1 is an epimorphism, but there are no global sections.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Well-pointedness means that for all $f, g: A \to B$, if for all $x : 1 \to A$, $f \circ x = g \circ x$, then $g = f$. One generally also includes the requirement that $1$ is not the initial object in the definition of "well-pointed". The category of sheaves on $S^1$ does not satisfy this property.

Comment: OK, so in other words, if the functor of global sections is faithful.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Correct - together with the requirement that 1 is not initial.

Comment: Have you seen the additional parts of the definition of a [constructively well-pointed topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-pointed+topos#in_constructive_mathematics)? Presumably you need a model that refutes one of those aspects.